# OceanWP + Woo: How to add on STORE Site Default Attribute Value between Product name and Price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have add Product in Woo: Theme OceanWP

ex.
Name product: Product1

attribute1: A

attribute2: B

attribute3: C

attribute4: D

On Product Page I see Name Product and all check attribute I have in Additional Information with is generate automated in Woo and automated add to Single Product Page.

On Main Store page I have Only Photo, Product Name, Price ( rest options I off in Woo like Tags, Categories, Stars, There is no options to show Attributes in main site store)

So… I Want to display only in Main Store Page ( and all sliders, sliders show this same information with I check in Woo) only one attribute value ex.

Picture
Product name
Just one ATTRIBUTE VALUE
PRICE

When I add this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'additional_info_under_add_to_cart', 35 );
function additional_info_under_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product && ( $product->has_attributes() ) ) {
        wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
    }
}
```

I see this:
https://prnt.sc/117f4e6

Ok, I see my All add attribute in each other products, but now, how to isolate just the value of attribute Model between Product name and Price, and there will be a fix it ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ocean_before_archive_product_price` hook.

```
// shows the "Model" attribute between the product name and price
add_action( 'ocean_before_archive_product_price', 'add_attribute_after_shop_loop_item_title', 1 );
function add_attribute_after_shop_loop_item_title() {

    global $product;
    // if the slug of the "Model" attribute is "model" use "pa_model"
    if ( $product->get_attribute( 'pa_model' ) ) {
        echo '<p>' . $product->get_attribute( 'pa_model' ) . '</p>';
    }

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*